# How to get title bar buttons like Office 2010?

Tags: wpf, ms-office, ribbon-control

how is it possible to give to the mininum / maximum / close buttons of the title bar of a WPF application the same style as in [Office 2010](http://img.labnol.org/di/office-word-2010.png)?

As you can see, the buttons are well integrated in the title bar.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Oh, so you want to make them different from *every other window* on the user's computer so that they're guaranteed to think of your app as "difficult to use"? Not sure that's what I'd do... Microsoft Office can get away with things that the average app developer can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [GlassWindow](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=fluidkit&DownloadId=30263) in [FluidKit](http://fluidkit.codeplex.com/) at [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/).

Also go through

[Custom Window Chrome in WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at that